# Icon part of SO Logo - Do we own it?

Tags: discussion, logo

Do we own the icon part of the SO logo?

[image]

Reason I ask is I came across this website that is using it as an icon for their Industry News: http://forwardermagazine.com/

Comment: It's definitely protected, but maybe not worth going after. SO's decision. Was probably a mistake, a web designer Googling "industry icon" or something and seeing the logo

Comment: I thought it was... Thanks for clearing that up @Pekka웃

Comment: The are using FontAwesome and probably didn't realize that this icon is a brand icon (although ist clearly labelled as such).